# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element error locating element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a program which uses the python selenium webdriver and I get the following runtime error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='id_login']"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.1
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Type your username" required="" id="id_login" xpath="1">16)
```

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="c:\\Chrome1\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.jstor.org")
print(driver.title)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='inline-block plm']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_login']").send_keys('xxxxxx@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Is the error showing for the element with xpath //a[@class='inline-block plm'] also or only for the input with id id_login?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `selenium` could not localize the element because it was not on the site or it did not load. I suggest you using the `WebdriverWait()` function. It will wait X seconds until the element is clickable. If it will still not be, it will throw an error.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class='inline-block plm']')))
```

Answer (score 0):

More effective if you direct directly to this url:

https://www.jstor.org/action/showLogin?redirectUri=/

And use selenium wait to solve your issue.

```
driver.get('https://www.jstor.org/action/showLogin?redirectUri=/')
user_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='id_login']")))
user_name.send_keys('xxxxxx@gmail.com')
```

Although your xpath will work, using an id looks better **`.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id_login"))`**

You need following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Username** field you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.jstor.org/")
  ebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.inline-block.plm"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#id_login"))).send_keys("SunilTirupathi@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.jstor.org/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='inline-block plm']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='id_login']"))).send_keys("SunilTirupathi@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: jstor]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)